# Cookie não existe

Tags: php

Estou tentando passar alguns dados de uma página para outra, porem não está funcionando corretamete.

> http://exemplo/teste/index.php

```
<?php
$nome = "JOSIMAR";
setcookie("nomee", $nome);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location=' ../demostracao/usuarios/index.php'</script>"; 
?>
```

> http://exemplo/demostracao/usuarios/index.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE["nomee"]))
{
    echo "Existe";
}else
{
    echo "Nao existe";
} 
?>
```

está me retornando 'nao existe' , alguem me da uma luz?

Comment: No console do navegador o cookie aparece? talvez voce precise setar o diretório do cookie para `/`, pois do jeito que voce esta setando ele pode ficar apenas acessivel em `/teste/` e nao aparecer em `/demonstracao/`

Comment: Estou usando o **Edit This Cookie** e ele não aparece lá!

Comment: `setcookie("nomee", $nome', time()+3600);  /* expira em 1 hora */`, tente assim...

Comment: Tente como @DanielCosta falou, `setcookie("CookieTeste", "", time() + 3600, "/");` passando parametro do diretorio.

Comment: Opa pessoa consegui más de uma forma modificada, irei responder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido conforme citado por o amigo @Augusto, más com umas modificações necessárias ficando assim :

> index.php

```
<?php
$nome = "JOSIMAR";
setcookie("nomee", "$nome", time() + 3600, "/");
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location=' ../demostracao/usuarios/index.php'</script>";
?>
```

> recebe.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE["nomee"]))
{
    echo "Existe";
}else
{
    echo "Nao existe";
}
?>
```